# Writing $ |a+b|-|b| $ in piecewise format.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is from Spivak calc. ch-1. Here I used the definition of absolute value function and got the following :
$$
|a+b|-|b| =
\begin{cases}
(a+b)-b  & a+b≥0, b≥0 \\
(a+b)-(-b)  & a+b≥0, b<0 \\
-(a+b)-b  & a+b<0, b≥0 \\
-(a+b)-(-b) & a+b<0, b<0
\end{cases}
$$
Here the inequalities aren't probably solved. I mean I would like to show separate inequalities for $ a \ \text{and} \ b $.So I tried that for the second pair of inequalities this way:

$$ a+b≥0 : a+b>0 \ \text{or} ,
 \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{ 
 a=-b
} 
$$
$$  a+b>0, \  \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{ b<0 } \implies -b>0  $$
$$ \text{ So}, \  \ a+b-b>0 \implies  \bbox[5px,border:2px solid black]
{ a>0 } $$
Now putting $ a=-b$ in second line right above it gives ,
\begin{align}
 (a+b)-(-b) =a+2b \\
=-b+2b=b,b<0
\end{align}

$$
|a+b|-|b|=|-b+b|-|b|=-|b|
$$
So, it holds.

But in other cases it's hard to split those inequalities like this(I couldn't). Is it really possible?

Comment: Always start with $b$. For example, for the second case, you have $b<0, a+b \ge 0$
Thus, $-b>0, a \ge -b >0 \implies a > 0$ and so forth

Comment: @Vasili but what about the first case ? It doesn't work.

Comment: In the first case, we have $b \ge 0, a \ge -b$ and that will be the solution. You won't always get restriction for $a$ which does not have $b$.

Comment: @Mysticmystic, could you tell me what you desire to get in relation to your post ? I am sorry but I have not understood it yet. If you explain me it clearly, I will try to help you.

Comment: $|b|$ breaks whether $b < 0$ or $0 \le b$. $|a+b|$ breaks when $a+b < 0$ or $0 \le a+b$. The latter two inequalities solve to $a < -b$ or $-b \le a$. There is no point in comparing $a$ to $0$ - the function does not change behavior there. So there are four cases: $$b < 0, a < -b\\b< 0, -b \le a\\0 \le b, a < -b\\0\le b, -b \le a$$ On each of those domains, the absolute values are removable with appropriate changes of sign.